# write log file to html per thread

Tags: java, html, logging

I have a application that write a log file to .log.
But now i make a html jar file to implement to the application (1 log per request).
The problem is when 2 or more thread running at the same time, the html log is mixed up.

Example:
aaa.log and bbb.log

aaa.log content contain bbb.log content vice versa

how to make it separate log file with own content.

```
ctx.htmllogger = new HTMLLogger(
        ctx.control.getCodeValue(), 
        ctx.AvailRequest.getTrip().getSegmentProductType()
        .getCodeValue(), ctx.OPT_TYPE);
String htmllogdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

```
htmllogdir = htmllogs + "\" + ctx.htmllogger.getCurrentTS( "ddMMyyyy" ) + "\" + ctx.OPT_TYPE.toLowerCase();
ctx.htmllogger.MakeDirectories( htmllogdir );
```

`try {

    ctx.htmllogger.initLogger(DlgKuoni.class.getCanonicalName(), htmllogdir);

} catch (IOException e) {
    ctx.htmllogger = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ctx.htmllogger.startHTMLLog();`

Appreciated who help me.

Comment: Do you create a log file for each thread? Can you post some code?

Comment: You should edit your question and add code there, more readable!

Comment: ctx.AvailRequest.getTrip().getSegmentProductType().getCodeValue(), ctx.OPT_TYPE );

this code is getting request param and make html file name

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at log4j (and maybe self4j). There is really no need th handle these things on your own.
That can all be configured with log4j, including html-formatter etc.

Comment: making html log is because of when there a error on application, i can make the html log string become red color so i can views it by color of text

Comment: I know you would like to just get the solution for your problem and this is OK. I just wanted to show you an other way, where you may not run into these problems or solve them by just configuring. If log4j is new to you, than it may be some overhead, but you can believe me, that you will not regret working with it.

Comment: i have default log file using commons-logging

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have a bug in your program.  Most likely you have a global/shared variable used by both threads to access the log.

I suggest you have a resource for your log which is visible to only one thread at a time.  This avoids the chance for confusion.